# How can I track moving items in real-time in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, real-time, tracking, dashboard, warehouse

I saw this Warehouse Dashboard on Youtube (Login as Vendor without any username or password)
https://pbiewarehousedemo.azurewebsites.net/warehouse-summary 
and I was wondering how they created this Warehouse Map with the moving items. It seems to be like a real-time position tracker. So I thought I could use this to track my products in a production line to create a digital shadow. Unfortunately they just used it as an example for embedded Power BI in their Youtube video and don't know how this was created.

Does anyone know how to creat such a real-time tracking dashboard? I didn't find anything on the internet.

You would help me a lot if someone had an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That report is a bit of a cheat, the visual is not an actual visual it is a video.

[image]

Real time tracking can sort of be done. 
It would be some thing like

- Vehicle transmits a GPS to database/api/Azure Function
- Data get sent to a database
- A function/flow/data factory that refreshes the dataset with the
  latest data

That works well for tracking objects around a wide region for a specific location around for example a factory, it would have to be a created custom visual, or maybe a R/Python Visual

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I already expected it to be something like that. So I probably just gonna show the product ID on each machine, without the actual movements.